# Debugger step into IInterceptionBehavior. Invoke

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library, visual-studio-debugging, interceptor, unity-interception

I have unity interceptor implemented IInterceptionBehavior.Invoke, everything works just fine, however in VS-debugger if I click step-into  on a proxy object, it is not working (I would expect to jump into target method or at least to my Invoke methode). VS debugger behaves like step-over. should I provide some attribute as hint to  VS to know it should jump into it and not ignore it

thanks